# jquery toggleclass with closest

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of items like so

```
<div id="items">

<figure>
<img>
<figcaption>
</figcaption>
</figure>

</div>
```

On clicking the figure I am using the code to toggle a class 'figover' to display some info

```
$('figure').on('click', function () {
$('figcaption').removeClass('figover');
$(this).closest('figure').find('figcaption').toggleClass('figover');        
});
```

This works as intended for one thing. It toggles figover when clicking an item and shows the info. When clicking another item figover is removed from the old item and toggled in the new one. But if I click on the item with figover toggled on, figover is not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter out current clicked `figure` elements child `figcaption` while removing class from all `figcaption`. try this:

```
$('figure').on('click', function () {
 $('figcaption').not($(this).closest('figure').find('figcaption')).removeClass('figover');
 $(this).closest('figure').find('figcaption').toggleClass('figover');        
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure which solution is best, both work but I'll be using this. Thanks for pointing out the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the selector used on the `removeClass` act on all the figcaption elements (the current element children too).

You can exclude the current element children from the selector used from the `removeClass` and toggle its class; in this way all the other occorunces are removed from the `removeClass` and the current element toggle the class (by adding or removing the class on it).

Code:

```
$('figure').on('click', function () {
    var $curCap=$(this).closest('figure').find('figcaption');
    $('figcaption').not($curCap).removeClass('figover');
    $curCap.toggleClass('figover');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T5B3f/

Comment: Thanks kindly for the explanation